# Is it possible not to override default grid filters when clicking on a filtered grid URL?

Tags: grid, filter

Using the following code

```
$filter = 'foo=1&bar=2';
$filter = base64_encode($filter);
$url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/moo/index', array('filter'=>$filter));
```

The URL stored in the `$url` var would thus link to the `moo` grid, with `foo` filtered to 1 & `bar` filtered to 2.

By default, `foo` is filtered to 0 and `bar` is filtered to 0 as well.

After accessing the `$url`, the grid will keep loading with your newly applied filters (`foo` = 1 and `bar` = 2) until you restart your admin session. Is it somehow possible to force Magento not to do this? I.E.

```
$filter = 'foo=1&bar=2&DoNotRemember=1';
$filter = base64_encode($filter);
$url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/moo/index', array('filter'=>$filter));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your grid class and add this in the constructor:

```
$this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);
```

Comment: At some point I'm going to need to start splitting my salary with you.

Comment: the sooner the better :)

Comment: Interestingly enough, this does seem to resolve manual filters applied. But after clicking the link to the `$url` set as mentioned above, it seems to save the parameters, even though the flag is set to false. Going to keep digging.

Comment: Ah man, this does look troubling. Manually applying filters after setting `saveParametersInSession(false);` works as expected, correctly. However, when clicking on a URL encoded link, as mentioned in the question, these filters are saved as the "default" filters, even when navigating back to the grid. The only way to revert is to log out & back in again. Going to keep digging.